# Scala - Turning RDD[String] into a Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, jackson, rdd

I have a very large file that contains individual JSONs which I would like to iterate through, turning each one into a Map using the Jackson library:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper import com.fasterxml.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule 
import com.fasterxml.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper 
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper 
mapper.register(DefaultScalaModule) 
val lines = sc.textFile(fileName)
```

on a single JSON string, I can perform without issues:

```
mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](JSONString)
```

to get my map.

However, if I try the following by iterating through an RDD[String] like so I get the following error:

```
lines.foreach(line=> mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]])


org.apache.Spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

I can do lines.take(10000) or so and then work on that but this file is so huge I can't "take" or "collect" the whole file in one go and I want to be able to use the same solution across files of all different sizes.

After the string becomes a Map, I need to perform functions on it and write to a string, so any solution that allows me to do that without going over my allocated memory will help. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use the built-in capabilities of **Spark** to read a `JSON` file?

Comment: The text file is separate jsons appended together. If I pull in as sc.textFile(fileName) I can iterate through each individual JSON file as a string and do something like println, and I want to continue to treat it as a string. I cannot make it into a map while it exists an rdd, but I can if I turn it into an array with take or collect. My issue is it's too big for that, and I have no idea why I can perform functions on the Array[String] but not the rdd[String]

Comment: _"I have no idea why I can perform functions on the Array[String] but not the rdd[String]"_ because who knows what kind of black magic using reflection is **jackson** doing which makes the task non-serializable _(something vital to run the task in a cluster)_; also, anyways `Map[String, Object]` is an extremely unsafe data structure. - Again, if your file is `JSON` per line then you can just read it with **spark** out of the box.

Comment: I do have a way to get it into a safer data structure down the line. But could you tell me how I could read it with spark out of the box? I don't want a data frame, either a string or a map. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with a `DataFrame`? Or what about turning it into a `Dataset[SomeCaseClass]` that properly represents your data? - Anyways, if you insist on going this route, then I recommend looking at other JSON library like **circe** which shouldn't have this serializable problem.

Comment: I'll take a look at circe. I originally read this file in as a dataframe and accessing values (I tried many different ways, including with a schema) from a dataframe vs map was a significant performance difference, I'd really prefer a map. Also the JSONs are changeable.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this with the below:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
val myMap = JSON.parseFull(jsonString).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]]
```

The above will work on an RDD[String]

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json._` was deprecated even before I started using **Scala** 5 years ago. You are using an extremely old **Scala** version and as such an extremely old **Spark** version... You really should upgrade and use best practices.